# I want to hide the search bar in my webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am making a strip menu which turns to hamburger when the page shrinks, am doing it with js, but the search bar is next to it and gets ugly when it toggles, question is how to hide the search bar when the ham-menu is clicked.. I think i can add some lines inside the function to hide it, i have tryed a several options but didn't work

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const topNav = document.getElementsByClassName('top-nav')[0]
const search = document.getElementsByClassName('search-box')[0]


toggleButton.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    topNav.classList.toggle('active') & search.style.display('none')
    
})
```

Comment: you can use jquery,   `$('.top-nav').toggleClass('active')`

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const topNav = document.getElementsByClassName('top-nav')[0]
const search = document.getElementsByClassName('search-box')[0]


toggleButton.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    topNav.classList.toggle('active')
    if (search.style.display != 'none')
        search.style.display = 'none'
    else search.style.display = 'block'
})
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
<input class="search-box"/>
</div>
<button class="toggle-button">Toggle</button>
```